# Python 3.7.7 ImportError: cannot import name 'LSHash' from 'lshash'

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm using *Python 3.7.7*. I have a class defined like

```
class LSHash(object):
  def __init__(self, hash_size, input_dim, num_hashtables=1,
             storage_config=None, matrices_filename=None, overwrite=False):
  #...
```

when I try to import the Python class `LSHash` from the `lshash` module with

```
from lshash import LSHash
```

I have an `ImportError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 3, in <module>
    from lshash import LSHash
ImportError: cannot import name 'LSHash' from 'lshash' (/Users/loretoparisi/Documents/MyProjects/lshash/lshash/__init__.py)
```

The `lshash.py` imports of future:

```
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals, division, absolute_import
from builtins import int, round, str,  object  # noqa
from future import standard_library
standard_library.install_aliases()  # noqa: Counter, OrderedDict, 
from past.builtins import basestring   # noqa:

import future        # noqa
import builtins      # noqa
import past          # noqa
import six           # noqa
```

The code to reproduce the error is [here](https://github.com/loretoparisi/lshash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make relative imports in `__init__`.py file, like this:

```
from .lshash import *
from .storage import *
```

[Intra-package References](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

[Good example](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules)